# Linq joined tables in gridview

Tags: linq-to-sql, gridview

```
var result = from p in dc.People
             join d in dc.Departments
             on p.fk_dep_id equals d.pk_dep_id
             select p;

return result.ToList();
```

The linq query above will select all People, together with the full name of the department they are assigned to. This result contains the Department data in an object "Department", which I can see when debugging.

However, when adding this result to a gridview, the joined data triggers an error:

```
"A field or property with the name "Department.name" was not found on the selected data source.
```

I tried doing the following in the Gridview:

```
<asp:BoudField DataField="Department.Name" HeaderText="Department" SortExpression="Department.Name" />
```

Any ideas on how to display such a "joined" columns in a Gridview, by using linq2sql data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DataField` should be a property name of the object in the data source. You can't use complex expressions like that. For this you need the `TemplateField`:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" 
             Text="<%# (Eval("Department") as Department).Name %>" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```